# pointer initialised to array a by *p=a++; but its giving error why? what's the logic behind that?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++14

i was studying pointers and a quiz was there and here's a question which says *p=a++; where a was an array with 4 elements in it. it's showing error of lvalue requiring on increment operator. why?

what i was thinking that it should point to the 2nd element of array i.e.; a[1]. but i think the error is because here the pointer is not initialised with some value but it is given a operation in front of it. (i might be wrong).

here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int *p = a++;
    cout<< *p <<endl;
}
```

Comment: `a` is an array. Arrays are not pointers. You cannot increment an array. In many cases, including this one, arrays decay to pointers, but these pointers are temporary. You cannot increment a temporary either.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI but i'm not increasing a pointer. all i want is to point to the incremented value of a. which should be the index 1.

Comment: "but i'm not increasing a pointer" You are currently not doing anything at all, since this program does not compile. However `++` is called "increment operator" for a good reason: it increments a variable, as in changes its value to one bigger. So I figure you attempt to increment `a`. If you don't need that, then perhaps don't use the increment operator. Try `a+1` instead.

Comment: *"all i want is to point to the incremented value of a."*  What you you mean by that? What your current code said, if it was valid is: Let `p` point to the first element in the array. Then increase the pointer in `a` so the array starts at the second element. So: What do you expect `p` and `a` to be, after this line of code executed (which it won't anyways, because it's a syntax error)

Comment: BTW: "it's giving error" is not a valid problem description. Please always include the *exact* error message and the location in the code, the error points to.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler might give you an error message like:

```
error: cannot increment value of type 'int[4]'
```

This is because, like with all automatic variables, you can't change where it's poiting in memory. Compare with trying to move a non-array variable:

```cpp
int x;
(&x)++; // Error, can't be done either
```

Also note that with `a++` you try to move where `a` points a full `int[4]` worth - not a single `int`. Even if you *could* move where `a` points, you'd immediately make it point out of bounds (of where it originally pointed).

I'm assuming that you wanted it to point at the second element (inside itself), so instead of trying to move where `a` points in memory after assigning its original address to `p`, you could add another variable that points at the second element in `a`:

```cpp
int* p = a;
int* sa = a + 1; // use `sa` instead of `a` later
```

You now can use `sa[0]` up to `sa[std::size(a)-2]` safely since `&a[1] == &sa[0]` and `&a[size(a)-1] == &sa[std::size(a)-2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to increment the array by doing `a++` since it is an array. In order to set the pointer to the second index of the array you would need to do it this way:

```
int *p = &a[1];
```

This way you would be able to increment your pointer to the next index by doing `p++`;

Comment: Minor nitpick: `int *p = a++;` (if it could be done) would assign the address of the first element in `a` to `p`, just like `int *p = &a[0];` will.